How to embed Multiple parameter types in a single type container with a class constraint?
I would like to create a Haskell class which perform operations on multiples data types. For an example, I would like to add a value on all elements of a Map structure and retrieve a new Map.
To do that I created a class and instances with 3 types using the MultiParamTypeClasses and FlexibleInstances pragma :
class OPER a b c where
  add::  a -> b ->  c
 
instance OPER (Maybe Double) (Maybe Double) (Maybe Double)  where
  add (Just a) (Just b) = Just (a + b)
  add _ _ = Nothing

instance OPER (Map.Map Int (Maybe Double)) (Maybe Double) (Map.Map Int (Maybe Double)) where
  add ma mbdlb = Map.map (\mbi -> add mbi mbdlb ) ma

It work fine and give me what I want :
main = do
  print $ (add (Just (3.5::Double)) (Just (9.7::Double)) :: (Maybe Double))
  print $ (add (Map.fromList [(1,Just 3.4),(2,Just 9.4),(3::Int,Just (9.7::Double)),(4,Just 4.8)]) (Just (9.7::Double)) :: (Map.Map Int (Maybe Double)))


Just 13.2
fromList [(1,Just 13.1),(2,Just 19.1),(3,Just 19.4),(4,Just 14.5)]

Now, I would like to embed all possibles types in an AnyData type. I created the following :
data AnyData = forall s . (Show s, Eq s) => DAT s 

and the instances :
instance Show AnyData where
  show (DAT a) = "DAT "++show a

instance OPER AnyData AnyData AnyData  where
  add (DAT a) (DAT b) =  DAT (add a b)

But when I try to compile, I get the message :
        • Could not deduce (OPER s s1 s0) arising from a use of ‘add’
          from the context: (Show s, Eq s)
            bound by a pattern with constructor:
                       DAT :: forall s. (Show s, Eq s) => s -> AnyData,
                     in an equation for ‘add’
            at testMultiFun_test5.hs:40:8-12
          or from: (Show s1, Eq s1)
            bound by a pattern with constructor:
                       DAT :: forall s. (Show s, Eq s) => s -> AnyData,
                     in an equation for ‘add’
            at testMultiFun_test5.hs:40:16-20
          The type variable ‘s0’ is ambiguous
          Relevant bindings include
            b :: s1 (bound at testMultiFun_test5.hs:40:20)
            a :: s (bound at testMultiFun_test5.hs:40:12)
        • In the first argument of ‘DAT’, namely ‘(add a b)’
          In the expression: DAT (add a b)
          In an equation for ‘add’: add (DAT a) (DAT b) = DAT (add a b)
       |
    40 |   add (DAT a) (DAT b) =  DAT (add a b)
       |                               ^^^^^^^  

I tried to modify my AnyData type declaration with :
data AnyData = forall s . (OPER s s s, Show s, Eq s) => DAT s 

or
data AnyData = forall s s1 s2 . (OPER s s1 s2) => DAT s 

with the AllowAmbiguousTypes Pragma.
and more simply :
data AnyData = forall s . DAT s 

but I always have the same kind of message.
• No instance for (OPER s s1 s0) arising from a use of ‘add’
        • In the first argument of ‘DAT’, namely ‘(add a b)’
          In the expression: DAT (add a b)
          In an equation for ‘add’: add (DAT a) (DAT b) = DAT (add a b)
       |
    43 |   add (DAT a) (DAT b) =  DAT (add a b)
       |     

As far as I understand, the compiler doesn't understand that there can be different types to my add function when I use it with AnyData and can't resolve the inference of types.
Is there a solution to embed all the types usable with my OPER class in a single type (to make a list of results) ?
Are there other ways of doing this? with GADTs or type families ?

Hint: Consider what add (Dat (Just 3)) (Dat (M.fromList [(1, Just 2)]) is supposed to be...

Sorry but I don't understand what you mean.

You might like Ghosts of Departed Proofs.

Your AnyData doesn't say what type of data is stored inside it (which is the whole point of what you're trying to do). So when you say add (DAT a) (DAT b) =  DAT (add a b), there's no way of knowing what types a and b are, and thus no way of knowing whether there is an instance OPER a b c that would allow you to add them. And you can't add constraints to AnyData itself to guarantee there will be the OPER instance you need, because the type information needed is not about a single AnyData it's about two of them used together (3 including the result).

I think the closest you can do to what you asked for directly is something like https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.20.0.1/docs/Data-Dynamic.html (so no need to roll your own AnyData), which gives you enough runtime type information to do all the type checks yourself (but you have to do it yourself). I don't think I would find that an acceptable solution myself, and think there is likely a better answer for you real goal, but it would require taking a step back and addressing what you want this for in a different way (so a different question really).

@JeanJouX The example by Cubic is the issue you are facing. If you allow instance OPER AnyData AnyData AnyData then you are essentially allowing adding any type with any type, even when these types are distinct and can not be added together. Cubic used Dat (Just 3) which hides the Maybe Int value under Dat, so that the resulting type is AnyData. Then Dat (M.fromList [(1, Just 2)] similarly hides a Map Int (Maybe Int) under a Dat, so the resulting type is AnyData. How can we add these two values of type AnyData in a meaningful way? Since we can't, the instance can't exist.

Short answer
Add a type parameter to AnyData and may be use GADTs for less constraints in instance declarations.
Type parameter for AnyData
All the code here and below works with GHC, version 8.8.4, also using compiler switch -Wall.
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class OPER a b c where
    add :: a -> b -> c

data AnyData s = DAT s

instance Show s => Show (AnyData s) where
    show (DAT a) = "DAT " ++ show a

instance (OPER a a a) => OPER (AnyData a) (AnyData a) (AnyData a) where
    add (DAT x1) (DAT x2) = DAT (add x1 x2)

instance OPER Int Int Int where
    add nA nB = nA + nB

main :: IO ()
main = 
    do
        print ( add ( DAT ( 7 :: Int ) ) ( DAT ( 13 :: Int ) ) :: (AnyData Int) )

GADTs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

class OPER a b c where
    add :: a -> b -> c

data AnyData s where
    DAT :: (OPER s s s) => s -> AnyData s

instance Show s => Show (AnyData s) where
    show (DAT a) = "DAT " ++ show a

instance OPER (AnyData s) (AnyData s) (AnyData s) where
    add (DAT x1) (DAT x2) = DAT (add x1 x2)

instance OPER Int Int Int where
    add nA nB = nA + nB

main :: IO ()
main = 
    do
        print ( add ( DAT ( 7 :: Int ) ) ( DAT ( 13 :: Int ) ) :: (AnyData Int) )

The advantage of GADTs is that you do not need to add a constraint to a in the the instance declaration for of OPER (AnyData a) (AnyData a) (AnyData a).
Other trials
I found one more depreciated alternative using a constraint in data type declaration.
The compiler warns: "-XDatatypeContexts is deprecated: It was widely considered a misfeature, and has been removed from the Haskell language."
Additionally you have to apply UndecidableInstances to avoid the following error:
    • Variable ‘s’ occurs more often
        in the constraint ‘OPER s s s’
        than in the instance head ‘Show (AnyData s)’
      (Use UndecidableInstances to permit this)
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Show (AnyData s)’
   |
17 | instance (OPER s s s, Show s) => Show (AnyData s) where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

DEPRICATED: Constraint in data type declaration (DatatypeContexts)
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DatatypeContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module X2
    (
        main
    )
    where

class OPER a b c where
    add :: a -> b -> c

data (OPER s s s, Show s) => AnyData s = DAT s

instance (OPER s s s, Show s) => Show (AnyData s) where
    show (DAT a) = "DAT " ++ show a

instance (OPER s s s, Show s) => OPER (AnyData s) (AnyData s) (AnyData s) where
    add (DAT x1) (DAT x2) = DAT (add x1 x2)

instance OPER Int Int Int where
    add nA nB = nA + nB

main :: IO ()
main = 
    do
        print ( add ( DAT ( 7 :: Int ) ) ( DAT ( 13 :: Int ) ) :: (AnyData Int) )

NOTE: When applying add you have to add the the resulting type as well because the compiler cannot deduce (see in the final code line (AnyData Int)).
Final code?
Is this what you wanted to achieve?
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import qualified Data.Map as Map

class OPER a b c where
    add :: a -> b -> c

data AnyData s where
    DAT :: (OPER s s s) => s -> AnyData s

instance Show s => Show (AnyData s) where
    show (DAT a) = "DAT " ++ show a

instance OPER (AnyData s) (AnyData s) (AnyData s) where
    add (DAT x1) (DAT x2) = DAT (add x1 x2)

instance OPER Int Int Int where
    add nA nB = nA + nB

instance OPER (Map.Map Int (Maybe Double)) (Maybe Double) (Map.Map Int (Maybe Double)) where
  add ma mbdlb = Map.map (\mbi -> add mbi mbdlb ) ma

instance OPER (Maybe Double) (Maybe Double) (Maybe Double) where
  add (Just dA) (Just dB) = Just (dA + dB)
  add Nothing _ = Nothing
  add _ Nothing = Nothing

main :: IO ()
main = 
    do
        print ( add ( DAT ( 7 :: Int ) ) ( DAT ( 13 :: Int ) ) :: (AnyData Int) )
        print (add (Map.fromList [(1,Just 3.4),(2,Just 9.4),(3::Int,Just (9.7::Double)),(4,Just 4.8)]) (Just (9.7::Double)) :: (Map.Map Int (Maybe Double)))

Output
DAT 20
fromList [(1,Just 13.1),(2,Just 19.1),(3,Just 19.4),(4,Just 14.5)]


Note: -XDatatypeContexts was deprecated because it doesn't do anything useful. All it does is add a constraint to a constructor. It very much does not cause that constraint to be available when the constructor is matched on.
